# Adding binding to an IIS site returns ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have published my web API application on IIS, created a site, and then hit click on *Browse Web Site* to open it, and everything went well.

After I had added a binding so the application could be accessed through a path like `http://example.com` and then hit again the browse button on the new binding, the response was:

> example.com's server DNS address could not be found.
>
> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I had tried in different combinations like `www.example.com` or just `example` when adding the binding, also for given IP addresses, or for all IP addresses (marked with *), but it was the same behavior for the new binding.

What can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a host entry to resolve DNS.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/